# What happens from $ (1+(x+x^2))^n$ to $\sum_k {n \choose k} (x+x^2)^n$?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, binomial-theorem

I'm reading [Harris/Hirst/Mossinghoff's: *Combinatorics and Graph Theory*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441927239).

> [image]

I don't understand what happens from $\displaystyle \bbox[1px,border:1px solid black]{(1+(x+x^2))^n} $ to $\displaystyle  \bbox[1px,border:1px solid black]{\sum_k {n \choose k} (x+x^2)^n} $.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formula is that: $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}y^k=(1+y)^n$. Now substitute $y = x+x^2$ in the equation.

Comment: I've been able to reach to: $$\sum_k{n \choose k}1^k(x+x^2)^{n-k}$$ But I don't understand how he gets to the next step. Also, in this step, he writes: $$\sum_k{n \choose k}1^k(x+x^2)^{k}$$ I don't understand why he omitted the $n$ in $n-k$.

Comment: Since $\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{n-k} \Rightarrow \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}1^k(x+x^2)^{n-k} = \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{n-k}1^{k}(x+x^2)^{n-k} = \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}(x+x^2)^k$

Comment: Oh, thanks. Now what's unclear to me is the creation of: $$\sum_j {k \choose j} x^j$$ I don't understand why he's using $k$ nor why he used $j$.

Comment: It means that $j$ runs from $0$ to $n$